# QTextEdit::setTextFormat(Qt::LogText) does not exist anymore, what else can I use to log?

Tags: c++, qt, logging, qtextedit

I need a text logger in my C++ application, `QTextEdit` used to have this feature until Qt 3.3 but unfortunately it has been removed. Is there an alternative that I could use?

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. You could simply use
   `QTextEdit::setReadOnly(true)`, the
   old `Qt::LogText` flag basically just
   put the `QTextEdit` in plain-text
   read-only mode.
2. Or use `Q3TextEdit`, the Qt4
   compatibility class for the old Qt3 `QTextEdit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know Q3TextEdit existed, I will use it.

Comment: @ user363778 - Instead of using Q3TextEdit, it's better if you use QTextEdit in the above way. From Qt documentation - **"We strongly advise against using it (Q3TextEdit) in new code."**

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html) is what you are looking for.

It is optimized for dealing with plain text data and can be can put it in read only.